# How to close non-modal window on Mac?

Tags: macos, window

I have a window playing video, after playback I would like to close itself. I tried this on Yosemite with Swift:

If the window is modal, this works:

```
    dismissController(self)
```

If the window is not modal, I have tried both

```
    dismissController(self)
    removeFromParentViewController()
```

And the window won't close.

Answer (score 0):

try to use window object:

```
    if let window = self.view.window {
        window.performClose(sender)
    }
```